# Dependency Injection with NHibernate Event Listeners

Tags: c#, nhibernate, autofac

I'm trying to do simple constructor injection with NHibernate Event Listners, here is an example:

```
    public class FormGeneratorUpdate : IPostUpdateEventListener
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public FormGeneratorUpdate(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent @event)
    {
        string typeName = @event.Entity.GetType().Name;
        dynamic entity = @event.Entity;
        string filePath =
            $"{_env.ContentRootPath}\\App_Data\\FormGenerator\\{typeName}\\{entity.Id}.json";

        File.Delete(filePath);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            // Add some text to file
            Byte[] content = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(json);
            fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

I currently set up the NHibernate bytecodeProvider to the autofac implementation like so:

```
    NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvider =
            new AutofacBytecodeProvider(_container, new ProxyFactoryFactory(), new DefaultCollectionTypeFactory());
```

This seems to work just fine when building the session factory, but the question I have is how do I register an event listener with an NHibernate configuration without first instantiating it? Every way I can register it requires me to first instantiate the object like so:

```
cfg.SetListener(ListenerType.Update, new FormGeneratorUpdate());
```

Since the constructor is not empty it is throwing an error... I've tried just registering the event listeners with Autofac and tthat doesn't seem to work either, I believe I have to set it on the configuration as well some how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!!

For those wanting to use Dependency Injection with your event listeners autofac resolves them by the concrete type and not the interface. Originally I was registering all event listeners like so:

```
         builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
                  .AssignableTo<IPostUpdateEventListener>()
                  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

What I needed to do was register them like this:

```
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
                  .AssignableTo<IPostUpdateEventListener>()
                  .AsSelf()
                  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

When the AutofacObjectsFactory calls CreateInstance it tries to resolve it by using the concrete type of the event listener and not the interface type..

For those who are interested, I ended up registering the listners using xml configuration to avoid creating a default constructor on the event listeners...

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">

  <!-- an ISessionFactory instance -->
  <session-factory>
    <event type="post-insert">
      <listener class="FastTrack.FormGenerator.Listeners.FormGeneratorCreate, FastTrack"/>
    </event>
    <event type="post-delete">
      <listener class="FastTrack.FormGenerator.Listeners.FormGeneratorDelete, FastTrack"/>
    </event>
    <event type="post-update">
      <listener class="FastTrack.FormGenerator.Listeners.FormGeneratorUpdate, FastTrack"/>
    </event>
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then before you build the session factory just call .Configure("path-to-xml-file") on your NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration object.

**EDIT: It looks like we can actually register the listeners without instatiating it using this method:**

```
config.SetListeners(ListenerType.PostUpdate, new[] { typeof(FormGeneratorUpdate).AssemblyQualifiedName });
```

Comment: I'd suggest you set your answer as the accepted one - with the little tick below the score. I updated mine to specify registering as the interfaces is not the way to go, but still, it would be more obvious if your answer came up first.

Comment: Also, you might want to correct that last sentence as it reads *by using `_container.ResolveOptional()` and not `_container.ResolveOptional()`*

Comment: Okay will do, it says I have to wait before I accept mine as the answer.. Thanks for posting though, its generally hard to get feedback on NHibernate

Comment: Would you mind posting the complete code sample by removing any sensitive information? I tried to create a sample but I can't get it to work, whether I register the listeners as themselves or as the associated interfaces.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that I did actually register the events with the configuration, will post momentarily

Comment: Makes sense now. I was trying to do something 100% programmatically, without configuration file. Turns out you can still achieve it since the `SetListeners` method accepts an array of `string` containing the assembly-qualified type names. In your case, it would be like `config.SetListeners(ListenerType.PostUpdate, new[] { typeof(FormGeneratorUpdate).AssemblyQualifiedName });`. Also note that a single instance of the listener is created by NHibernate and then re-used, so you can't take lifetime-scoped dependencies in listeners.

Comment: Ah good catch, didn't see we could do it programmatically.. I did notice that they were reused.. I actually added a feature request in their Jira for hopefully making it so that they are resolved only when needed.. was pretty easy to change the core code to implement that, we'll see what happens

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right path since the [official Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/nhibernate.html) points to [this blog post](http://www.chadly.net/2009/05/dependency-injection-with-nhibernate-and-autofac/) where the only step is to override the default `BytecodeProvider` with the Autofac-provided one.

I think you shouldn't need to set the listeners yourself using `cfg.SetListener`.

**EDIT: My assumption below was wrong as per The Pax Bisonica's answer since it worked by registering the event handlers in the Autofac container as their concrete classes and not the associated interfaces**

When you registered the event listeners with Autofac, did you make sure you registered them as the associated interfaces? something like:

```cs
builder
    .RegisterType<FormGeneratorUpdate>()
    .As<IPostUpdateEventListener>();
```

I'm asking because I'm sure NHibernate would try to resolve against the interfaces.

Comment: I've removed the setlistener call and made sure that the type is registered with autofac and instead of breaking it just doesn't trigger the event